# 'Open Declaration' in Eclipse navigates to class files instead of to source files for Android Libraries

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I have two Android Projects 'A' and 'B'. 'B' depends on 'A' and is a Library. Whenever I'm in Project 'B' and hit 'Open Declaration' for a Java source file which resides in 'A', Eclipse navigates to the class file instead of the source file. This of course has several disadvantages!

I had a look at the build path of project 'B' to see if the referenced library 'A' has the correct path to it's source project which is the case.

Anyone knows how to fix that?

Here are the .classpath and project.properties files for each project:

**ProjectA *.classpath***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <classpath>
  <classpathentry kind="src" path="src"/>
  <classpathentry kind="src" path="gen"/>
  <classpathentry kind="con" path="com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.ANDROID_FRAMEWORK"/>
  <classpathentry kind="con" path="com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.LIBRARIES"/>
  <classpathentry kind="output" path="bin/classes"/>
</classpath>
```

**ProjectA *project.properties***

```
# This file is automatically generated by Android Tools.
# Do not modify this file -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE ERASED!
#
# This file must be checked in Version Control Systems.
#
# To customize properties used by the Ant build system use,
# "ant.properties", and override values to adapt the script to your
# project structure.

# Project target.
target=android-8
android.library=true
```

**ProjectB *.classpath***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<classpath>
  <classpathentry kind="src" path="src"/>
  <classpathentry kind="src" path="gen"/>
  <classpathentry kind="con" path="com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.ANDROID_FRAMEWORK"/>
  <classpathentry kind="con" path="com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.LIBRARIES"/>
  <classpathentry kind="output" path="bin/classes"/>
</classpath>
```

**ProjectB *project.properties***

```
# This file is automatically generated by Android Tools.
# Do not modify this file -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE ERASED!
#
# This file must be checked in Version Control Systems.
#
# To customize properties used by the Ant build system use,
# "ant.properties", and override values to adapt the script to your
# project structure.

# Project target.
target=android-8
android.library.reference.1=../ProjectA
```

Answer (score 19):

You can import the library project not only as an Android Lib (that is the way it's meant to be done), but also as a linked project in the usual "Java Build Path" menu.
Next, be sure to move this import to the top (at least more that "Library projects" entry) in the "Order and export" tab.

This works, but it a hack and it's dirty. This is not the way it is meant to be done... and when you deploy the app to the phone, eclipse will write a error message in the console saying that some apk cannot be found...

Still, I find it more convenient that linking to the class file.

I don't know what this is happening. My buddies in the office are running the same configuration than me, and they have not this issue, but it seems we are not the only ones whith this problem: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=20731

Comment: this is the fix I was looking for

Comment: Eclipse doesn't like when you put your lib at the top of "Order and Export" especially when it is before YourProject/gen entry. You should move down "Android dependencies" under your lib project.

Answer (score 11):

I had the same problem when my version of library project A was in "Properties > Java Build Path > Libraries", but not in "Properties > Java Build Path > Projects".

The problem was solved after I did the following:

1. Remove "Library Projects" from "Properties > Java Build Path > Libraries", which was added by "Properties > Java Build Path > Libraries"  (I am not sure if this step is necessary, but this is what I did).
2. Add project A to "Properties > Java Build Path > Projects".
3. Restart Eclipse (Indigo).  Somehow Eclipse recreates Library Projects in "Properties > Java Build Path > Libraries"

The .classpath should have the following:

```
<classpathentry combineaccessrules="false" kind="src" path="/A"/>
```

Actually navigating to class files was not the most annoying, but breaking in class files instead of java files during debugging was driving me crazy before this problem was solved.

Comment: This is the first solution that was helpful to me. And it works like a charm.
Is it possible to tell eclipse that it should put the libraries into the project tab?

Answer (score 8):

What worked for me: moving the lib projects up under the **Order** and **Export** tab - right below `/src` and `/gen` of the main project.

Comment: This seems to be correct.  I think that Android Dependencies contains the jar of all the libraries.  So by moving the Android Dependencies to bottom in order and export, the .java files will be found before the .class files whether 'Open Declaration' or in debugging.

Answer (score 1):

My first guess would be that you have a JAR with A's classes in it on B's build path. Check the Libraries tab. Can you show us your .classpath and project.properties files?

Comment: I added the requested files but I think that doesn't help much.

Comment: The .classpath files don't show anything out of the ordinary, so my theory about having a JAR on the classpath didn't pan out.

I would try removing Project A as a dependency. That should cause Project B build to fail (if it doesn't, use Project > Clean). Then add Project A back as a dependency to see if that clears things up. This is just grasping at straws, but the ADT plugins do seem to have some odd bugs around builds and dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

The following solution works for me:

Go to the android library project (in your case, it is A) setting -> Java Build Path -> Order and Export, make sure that the first entry is the source folder of the library (A). Then clean the library project and target project. Now it works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-309260
https://stackoverflow.com/a/77576173/9633499

you can toggle the registry flag "editor.preview.tab.navigation".
it works for me.