# Navigating to Declaration in new tab intelij

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea

Normaly I use `ctrl`+`left click` like it is described here:[Navigating to Declaration](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.2/navigating-to-declaration-or-type-declaration-of-a-symbol.html)

I want to achieve same behavior but in new window.

Analogous counterpart in everyday use is open webpage in a new tab:
[image]

How to navigate to declaration in new window?

Answer (score 0):

Hm, interesting.
I think you can do this by recording a macro.

This seems to do what you want:

[image: Macro: Go to declaration in new window]

You can start/stop the macro recording in menu "Edit -> Macros".
The action to Split and navigate to the next/previous split are in menu "Window -> Editor Tabs"

Answer (score 0):

you can toggle the registry flag "editor.preview.tab.navigation".

**refer: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-309260**

[image: https://i.imgur.com/qm9eB9l.png]
[image]
[image]
[image]
IDEA version: 2023.2.5